# Regex to include certain words but exclude another

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression which will check a URL contains certain words and excludes another.

The reason for this is I am trying to track traffic moving through my website and I don't want to count anyone who hits the Thank You page.

So for example:

- `http://www.mywebsite.com/register-now/` - MATCH
- `http://www.mywebsite.com/contact-us/` - MATCH
- `http://www.mywebsite.com/register-now/thank-you` - NO MATCH
- `http://www.mywebsite.com/contact-us/thank-you` - NO MATCH
- `http://www.mywebsite.com/thank-you` - NO MATCH

I have 2 words (`register-now` and `contact-us`) these must be in the URL. However I must ensure that 1 word (`thank-you`) is also not in the URL.

I have tried to use a negative lookahead to check that the URL does NOT contain thank-you but It is not working:

```
"^(?!.*\/thank\-you+)\/(contact\-us|register\-now)\/.*"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a single regex you can use negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*\/thank-you(?:\/|$))(?:.*\/)?(?:contact-us|register-now)\/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2JjwPA/5)

- `(?!.*\/thank-you(?:\/|$))` is negative lookahead that will fail the match if URL has `/thanks-you` or `/thank-you/`.
- Use `MULTILINE` mode if your text contains multiple URLs in each line.

Answer (score 1):

Separate for simplicity:

```
str.match(/(contact\-us|register\-now)/) && !str.match(/thank\-you/)
```